# How should we handle [handle]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Yes, there's a [handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handle) tag on Stack Overflow.  Its tag wiki reads a bit weird; it's almost like its a stand-in for [pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointer), although the questions immediately underneath it deal with "how to **handle** X".

I vote for some cleanup; those that actually mean "pointer" instead should be migrated over to "pointer".  Preferably some burnination of this tag, too?

Comment: You can't handle the success of this tag.

Comment: I wonder: I only know the phrase "file handle" (DOS/Windows world). Rename the tag?

Answer (score 13):

A handle is a pointer to a pointer (Wikipedia: [Handle (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)))

In some systems/languages, they are fundamental and very useful (handles to resources on the old Mac allowed it to do memory management and relocating memory (that was pointed to by the pointer) without invalidating the handle).

This type of thing can still be found in some systems today.

It's not just a pointer. It is something different. It shouldn't be burninated. It *should* be cleaned up.

Comment: I think [handle]'s existence is justified, but some uses need fixing.

Comment: I see handle more abstract: You can manage something to happen "behind the scenes" (in the OS) my showing a handle to the OS (and the OS can also return a handle to you, and the OS can invalidate a handle). Nobody would call C's `int **x` a *handle* IMHO.